# Add membership after upgrading to 5.36 error on PriceSet

Tags: civimember

After upgrading to 5.36, last version, when I try to add membership to an existant contact I received an error

> Deprecated: Non-static method CRM_Member_Form::getPriceSetID() should
> not be called statically in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\custom_php\CRM\Member\Form\Membership.php
> on line 672
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Member\Form.php:460
> Stack trace: #0
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\custom_php\CRM\Member\Form\Membership.php(672):
> CRM_Member_Form::getPriceSetID(Array) #1
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php(1600):
> CRM_Member_Form_Membership::formRule(Array, Array,
> Object(CRM_Member_Form_Membership)) #2
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Form.php(591):
> HTML_QuickForm->validate() #3
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Upload.php(136):
> CRM_Core_Form->validate() #4
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Upload.php(119):
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Member_Form_Membership),
> 'upload') #5
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Controller.php(203):
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_M in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Member\Form.php
> on line 460

The system have Wordpress 5.7 and PHP 7.3
It works if I use a PriceSet, but I use the standard membership option
[image]

In the Demo site 5.38 it works without any error. I try to set debug mode, but I haven't any other information in the log, just the Wordpress error

I see that there is another error when there a complete payment in a pay later event:

> Notice: Undefined variable:
> CRM16923AnUnreliableMethodHasBeenUserToDeterminePaymentProcessorFromEvent
> in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
> on line 2907
>
> Notice: Undefined index: 53 in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php
> on line 232
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'contribution' in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
> on line 4382
>
> Warning: Attempt to assign property 'total_amount' of non-object in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
> on line 2617
>
> Notice: Undefined index: contribution_recur_id in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
> on line 2634
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> CRM_Contribute_BAO_ContributionRecur::getTemplateContribution() must
> be of the type int, null given, called in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
> on line 2636 and defined in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionRecur.php:419
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(2636):
> CRM_Contribute_BAO_ContributionRecur::getTemplateContribution(NULL,
> Array) #1
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(4435):
> CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::repeatTransaction('7', Array, Array)
> #2 /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Contribution.php(688): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::completeOrder(Array, NULL, NULL,
> true) #3
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Contribution.php(502): in
> /home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionRecur.php
> on line 419

I have some doubt about price set values in the DB
[image: price set]
it seems that there is same record that I don't found the in the interface and the one I see I can't remove because the system tell me that is related to a member or event page. The id 14 in the price_set_entity table is related to the membership page, but I don't find any way to remove this relation.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your suggestion of the custom php I have solved the contribution problem. I have still the membership problem also removing the php custom file (I add the priceset table where it seems there are a dirty value that I could remove and I don't found in the interface)

Comment: Just curious: did you have CiviContribute enabled in the past and disabled it later?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11775)

Comment: I have CiviContributed enabled before, I found that is a problem related to the coma in the field cost (a know bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with the patch 5.36.1

Answer (score 1):

The backtrace is incomplete, but there's enough to see what's happening.

Someone has customized the code of this site with an "override" - note the line in the backtrace that mentions the file: `/home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php`.  Overrides are an older technique for customization before extensions existed, and are no longer recommended because of the exact issue you're seeing.

At some point, someone changed a few lines of code in this file:

```
/home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
```

Since every upgrade would overwrite that file, they made a copy here:

```
/home/gragorg/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php
```

This means the customization isn't overwritten with every upgrade - but if you don't keep that file up to date, you'll eventually run into a place where the old code no longer works with a newer version.

Because custom code is custom, I can't give a solid recommendation of how to resolve this - but if you have a way of finding out why a customization was introduced, it may not be necessary anymore, and you can delete the override file.

Note that if you have one override file, you might have others - and each one represents a similar time bomb.  I recommend allocating some time to removing these customizations and/or reimplementing them in extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This code changed relatively recently, but I can't see how this error would occur without an extension doing something mildly naughty.

I recommend doing the following and updating your question to reflect the results:

- Turn on [backtraces](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#using-the-built-in-debugging-tools) and replicate the error.  You should get more detail.  Post the backtrace as part of your question.  It will help identify a misbehaving extension.
- You can also try replicating the problem on the [demo site](https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org) to see if it's a problem specific to your site.  If you can replicate it on the demo site, that will get this escalated very quickly.

Comment: In the Demo site 5.38 it works without any error and I see that there is another error when there a complete payment in a pay later event (update first message)

Comment: I try in a local copy of the site to remove all extension and also the 5.37beta1 without any success, I think there is something on my data